# 'Invalid token' when using webapi thru Swagger authenticated by Azure AD

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I try to use AAD authentification on my WebApi (dotnet core 3.1) from swagger (Swashbuckle) client.
In my Startup class, I've configured like follow:

```
// Configure authentication
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme)
        .AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
```

my settings for AzureAd:

```
"AzureAd": {
 "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
 "ClientId": "xxxx-xxxxx1b",
 "Domain": "myoffice.onmicrosoft.com",
 "TenantId": "xxxxx-xxxxa5",
 "Scope": "api://xxxxxxxx-abc3cff48f1b/Full.Access",
 "ScopeDescription": "Full Access"
},
```

...

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
   c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
      {
          Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
          In = ParameterLocation.Header,
          Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows()
          {
               Implicit = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
               {
                   TokenUrl = new Uri($"Configuration["AzureAd:Instance"]}/{Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"]}/oauth2/v2.0/token"),
                   AuthorizationUrl = new Uri($"{Configuration["AzureAd:Instance"]}/{Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"]}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize"),
                   Scopes =
                   {
                        {
                            Configuration["AzureAd:Scope"],Configuration["AzureAd:ScopeDescription"]
                        }
                   }
               }
           }
      });
  c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
  {
      {
           new OpenApiSecurityScheme
           {
               Reference = new OpenApiReference
               {
                   Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                   Id = "Bearer"
               }
            },
            Array.Empty<string>()
            }
        });
    });
```

And in my Configure method:

```
 app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
 {
    c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
    c.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/{ApiVersion}/swagger.json", ApiName);
    c.OAuthClientId(Configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"]);
    c.OAuthScopeSeparator(" ");
 });
```

Swagger corectly log to AAD using my credential and when I use a route protected by `[Authorize]` the token is correcly sent to the API by I receive a 401 error with the following message:

```
www-authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token"error_description="The issuer 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/v2.0' is invalid"
```

The url `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/v2.0` is in the token in the iss section.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your error and your code, you do not tell your application the ValidIssuer. So you get the error. Please add the following code in the method `ConfigureServices` of  `startup.cs` file

```
services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(AzureADDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
        
                    ValidIssuers = new[] {
                     
                    },                    
            });
```

For example

- Configure Azure AD for your web API. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-overview)

  a. Create Azure AD web api application

  b.  [Expose  API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-expose-web-apis)
  [image]

  c. Configure code

  1. config file

  ```
  "AzureAd": {
   "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
   "ClientId": "[Client_id-of-web-api-eg-2ec40e65-ba09-4853-bcde-bcb60029e596]",  
   "TenantId": "<your tenant id>"
  },
  ```

  2. Add following code in the Stratup.cs

  ```
   services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
               .AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

           services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(AzureADDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme, options =>
           {
               options.Authority += "/v2.0";


               options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
               {
                  /**
                   *  with the single-tenant application, you can configure your issuers 
                   *  with the multiple-tenant application, please set ValidateIssuer as false to disable issuer validation 
                  */
                   ValidIssuers = new[] {
                     $"https://sts.windows.net/{Configuration["AzureAD:TenantId"]}/",
                     $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Configuration["AzureAD:TenantId"]}/v2.0"

                   },

                   ValidAudiences = new[]
                   {
                          options.Audience,
                          $"api://{options.Audience}"
                   }

               };

           });
  ```
- Configure swagger. For more details, please refer to the [blog](https://joonasw.net/view/testing-azure-ad-protected-apis-part-1-swagger-ui).

  a. Create Azure Web application

  [image]
  [image]
  [image]

  b. Configure API permissions. Regarding how to configure, you can refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis)

  c. code

  1. Install SDK

     ```
      <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.5.1" />
     ```
  2. config file

     ```
      "Swagger": {
          "ClientId": ""
       },
     ```
  3. Add the following code to Startup.cs in the ConfigureServices method:

     ```
      services.AddSwaggerGen(o =>
          {
              // Setup our document's basic info
              o.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
              {
                  Title = "Protected Api",
                  Version = "1.0"
              });

              // Define that the API requires OAuth 2 tokens
              o.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
              {
                  Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,

                  Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
                  {
                      Implicit = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
                      {
                          Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
                          {
                              { "api://872ebcec-c24a-4399-835a-201cdaf7d68b/user_impersonation","allow user to access api"}
                          },
                          AuthorizationUrl = new Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Configuration["AzureAD:TenantId"]}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize"),
                          TokenUrl = new Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Configuration["AzureAD:TenantId"]}/oauth2/v2.0/token")
                      }
                  }
              });

              o.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement{
              {
                  new OpenApiSecurityScheme{
                      Reference = new OpenApiReference{
                          Id = "oauth2",
                          Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme
                      }
                  },new List<string>()
                  }
              });

          });
     ```
  4. Add the following code to the Configure method:

     ```
      app.UseSwagger();
          app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
          {
              c.OAuthClientId(Configuration["Swagger:ClientId"]);
              c.OAuthScopeSeparator(" ");
              c.OAuthAppName("Protected Api");

              c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
          });
     ```
- Test
  [image]

Comment: Thanx a lot @Jim Xu, you saved my day!
Only the section with `services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>` was missing and I wouldn't have invented it myself!

Comment: @Jim Xu. Thanks. This helped me a lot. :)